# Entity or attribute if only one field beside key and attribute for other entity?

Tags: entity-framework

Let's say I have an entity `person` which has an attribute `Email`. But the person can have more than one Email address. So I have to put this attribute into a separate table.

But what I do not understand in this situation: Is `Email` now an entity or an attribute? I would say entity, because it has its own table. But I would say attribute, because this is the only function of it.

Answer (score 3):

Its has become its own Entity. You now have a 1:N relationship between Person and Email.

Comment: So an entity is not must not have attributes to be an entity?